# Sendgrid in a Visual studio Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sendgrid

I will add SendGid in a visual studio ASP.NET MVC 5 project. I have search on the internet, I haven't find some thing. can someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Sendgrid` nuget package available:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sendgrid/

Here is some documentation and sample code:

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp

Comment: Please elaborate more in your post, what have you tried and what was the failure in more detail. Your question is not clear about that.